# Executing a ruby script from the Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

```
Rails 3.2
```

I have a running rails application, with a Company MVC.

in the models/company.rb, I have the following method:

```
def save_company_pay_num
  return false unless self.valid?
  create_company_pay_num if self.company_pay_num.blank?
  res = save_check_company_pay_num
  unless res[0]
    errors.add(:set_company_pay_num, res[1].try{|r| r.split(':')[1].strip.capitalize})
    return false
  end
  true
end
```

I have about 1,000 companies, that need to have their pay numbers re-issued.

Is there a way, from the rails console (rails c), to execute a file, something like:

```
reset_pay_num.rb

company_ids=[
  '1',
  '2',
  '3',
  ...
]

company_ids.each do |c|
  company = Company.find(c)
  company.save_company_pay_num
end
```

Comment: You can directly copy paste the contents on console if they are not too much

Comment: I believe you will want to use a [rake task](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#custom-rake-tasks)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what's the reason for such behavior because at least you can put your script as a method inside some file required by rails but:

```
eval(File.read 'reset_pay_num.rb')
```

will do the trick.

Comment: This is a one time thing and i do not want to touch the app. I will

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create a rake-task for these purposes.